# How to stop code once a set time has been reached

Tags: python, timeout

I have asked this question previously but have gotten no valid responses. I would like players to complete my quiz but they only have a set time to do it and once it reaches the set time it ends the game and stops asking all the questions.

I have tried multiple different codes but displayed below is the latest one i am trying.

```
import time

max_time = int(input('Enter the amount of seconds you want to run this: '))
start_time = time.time()  
while (time.time() - start_time) > max_time:
    sys.exit()

question_1 = ("Question?")
option_1 =(" a. 54 \n b. 50 \n c. 47 \n d. 38")
print(question_1)
print(option_1)    
answer_1 = input(">")        
if answer_1.lower() == "a":
    print("Correct")  
else:
    print("Incorrect") 

question_a2 = ("Question 2?")
option_a2 = (" a. 4 \n b. 6 \n c. 8 \n d. 10")
print(question_a2)
print(option_a2)            
answer_a2 = input(">")
if answer_a2.lower() == "a":
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Incorrect")
end_time = time.time()
```

This code just keeps going through the questions like normal and nothing happens. I am fairly new and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use a [schedualer](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sched.html)

Comment: How would i use that? Where would i put it? Can you please expand?

Comment: If you want to be 100% dynamic, like immediately terminating the quiz, then this is a non-trivial task. You need to work with events and [concurrency](https://www.toptal.com/python/beginners-guide-to-concurrency-and-parallelism-in-python). I would not recommend that for a beginner. But there is an easier solution: Just check after each answer if the time is up, and then stop the quiz and don't count the last question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all, you should start using functions to minimize code duplication (copy&paste). An easy, but not really interactive solution is to check the time after a question is answered. Replace

```
if answer_a2.lower() == "a":
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Incorrect")
```

with

```
if (time.time() - start_time) > max_time:
    print("Sorry, you didn't answer in time")
    stop_quiz = True
elif answer_1.lower() == "a":
    print("Correct")
    total_points += 1
else:
    print("Incorrect")
```

Before you ask the next question, check if `stop_quiz` is True and only continue if it is False. I hope you get the idea. I also introduced a variable for counting correct answered questions.

UPDATE: Rewritten quiz by using a class for storage of points and time

```
import time

class Quiz:
  def __init__(self):
      self.total_points = 0
      self.stop_quiz = False
      self.start_time = time.time()
      self.max_time = int(input('Enter the amount of seconds you want to run this: '))

  def ask_question(self, question, options, correct_answer):
      if self.stop_quiz:
          return
      print(question)
      print(options)
      answer = input(">")
      if (time.time() - self.start_time) > self.max_time:
          print("Sorry, you didn't answer in time. The quiz is over")
          self.stop_quiz = True
      elif answer.lower() == correct_answer:
          print("Correct")
          self.total_points += 1
      else:
          print("Incorrect")

  def get_result(self):
      print("You got {} Points!".format(self.total_points))

quiz = Quiz()
quiz.ask_question("Question 1?", "a. 54 \nb. 50 \nc. 47 \nd. 38", "a")
quiz.ask_question("Question 2?", "a. 54 \nb. 20 \nc. 47 \nd. 38", "b")
quiz.get_result()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I actually already had that variable lol. My only question is stop_quiz doesn't work it goes to the next question?

Comment: This is probably a scope problem. I created a [working example](https://repl.it/@FriederSchuler/SimpelQuiz) by using a class and a class method.